# I slept, how should I respond to the professor?

Tags: graduate-admissions, research-process, professorship, email

It was late at night I sent an email to my professor. due to time differences, it was early over there. After sending an email I slept and my professor responds me and askeS me to skype in 2 hours. I slept and I didn't even open the email. How can I ask a meeting?
I didn't know he would ask me to have a skype, (in 2 hours after sending the mail):-O

could you please tell me how to respond my professor?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about academia.

Comment: I replied the email and wanted another Skype appointment. He has not answered me. are you still thinking my question is nonsense? :| and voting to close this question. I think it is one of the crucial questions.

Comment: I never said it was nonsense, only that it wasn't a good fit for this site.

Comment: Next time you email your professor, and there's a possibility he might want to have a Skype meeting with you in response, I suggest you list some times that you would be available (to prevent misunderstandings).

Comment: @CapeCode I disagree. It does fit under the context of "a question about ... Life as a graduate student, postdoctoral researcher, university professor". It _is_ somewhat academia specific, as very few other professions have the "always on" expectations which often come with academia. Ask this over at Workplace SE, and they'll castigate you for sending the email late at night ("don't do any work off the clock") and any answers would revolve around your employment contract and when it says you *must* be available. Academics don't have that, so what's expected is different than for non-academics.

Answer (score 23):

Students are allowed to sleep at night. In all likelihood the prof just forgot about the differences in timezone, or miscalculated the time difference.  Just answer something like :

Dear prof. XXX,

Sorry I missed your reply. It was 22:00 hours when I sent that message, and went to sleep immediately afterwards. Could we make another Skype appointment?

Best,
YYY

Answer (score 2):

Tell him "Sorry, I read your email just now. I am available for a skype meeting at (list of available times), please let me know which time suits you."
Then just make sure that you will check your email before these times, so don't put "in an hour" and then don't check your email. All in all, he is also just human and will understand that you can't always sit in front of your PC and answer your emails. Oh, and make sure to remember the time difference when proposing a meeting time, don't propose something that is in the middle of the night for either one of you.

Answer (score 2):

> Hi Prof X,
>   Sorry, I missed the email about the skype meeting, 
>   and the subsequent meeting.
>   It was Ypm here when I sent it.
>   Sending the email was the last thing I did before going to bed.
>   This is the first I've checked my emails since I got up.
>
> When would you like to  reschedule the meeting (remembering I am in the Ztimezone)?
>
> Kind Regards Nikki

There is nothing to be embarrassed about.

I personally would suggest that this professor (or anyone) expecting you to read any email within <12 hours (or even <24 hours) of receiving it is a bit much.
But that is a matter for you to discuss if you end up working with them:  expectations of frequency of communications and responses, .

It is obvious you couldn't have read it while asleep.
So I wouldn't worry about it.

Answer (score 2):

I hope I am not only one confused by futility of the question.
Just reply and mention difference in timezone with proposing another term considering it.